# How can i make a spinner prompt multiline?

Tags: android, spinner, prompt, multiline

I have a spinner that allows me to not show the first item in the list, but i can set my custom prompt. However whenever the prompt text spans more than one line it is cut off at the view bounds. How can i make the spinner prompt expand to accommodate more text?

I have tried modifying the view passed into the adapter to have multiple lines and also to ellipsize at the end, but nothing works.

Images for clarity:
With one line of text,
[image]

With several lines,
[image]

This is my code:

```
  languagesSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(EditProfileNationalityActivity.this, R.layout.no_default_spinner_item, new String[] {""}));

if(data.length>0) {
  String countries = spokenLanguages.toString().substring(0, spokenLanguages.toString().length() - 2);
        languagesSpinner.setPrompt(countries);
} else {

        Log.e("setting prompt to default");
        languagesSpinner.setPrompt("Please select languages");
}
```

and this is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:lines="2"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="1dp"
android:paddingRight="1dp"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" />
```

Per request, xml definition of spinner is as follows:

```
  <com.package.views.NoDefaultSpinner
            android:id="@+id/registration_stage_4_country_languages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="false" />
```

NoDefaultSpinner.java can be found here: https://github.com/geftimov/android-components/blob/master/components/src/main/java/com/eftimoff/components/views/spinners/nodefault/NoDefaultSpinner.java

I have modified it to have a custom getView() method in the SpinnerProxy like this:

```
 if (position < 0) {
            if (layoutResource == -1) {
                layoutResource = R.layout.no_default_spinner_item;
            }
            final TextView v =
                    (TextView) ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                            layoutResource, parent, false);
            v.setText(getPrompt());
            v.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

            return v;
        }
        return obj.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your source code:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(EditProfileNationalityActivity.this, R.layout.no_default_spinner_item, new String[] {""});
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.no_default_spinner_item);
languagesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: hi @jantursky that extra line does nothing because im overriding the touch on the spinner to then display something else (don't ask, UX nightmare haha) so i need the prompt to display multilined text, like in the images i just updated the question with.

Comment: Ok, I got it. So, please post the xml where you are defining the spinner and check if it has wrap_content for height attribute.

Comment: updated the question with more info, the spinner itself is indeed set to wrap_content

Comment: Well, it still depends on the root layout or even the whole xml structure for the whole layout where you have the layout. I'm suspicious about that marginTop attribute for instance.

Comment: but the marginTop is with respect to the parent layout, nothing to do with the values inside the spinner, because as you can see in the images, when there's only one line of text it works fine. if the margin was the issue it would also display incorrectly with one line of text don't you think?